# MPI on Windows: how to detect available library and processor count

Tags: windows, mpi, hpc, mpich, ms-mpi

I would like to automate detection of an MPI library under Windows 10/11 via a script.
So far the only options would be MPICH2 or MS-MPI, so I'd like to:

- Find an available installation (search for mpiexec.exe or spmd.exe)

For this, I'm currently running

```
# where mpiexec
C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\mpiexec.exe
```

and I can search for "Microsoft MPI" or "MPICH2" in the path string, but that's certainly not a general approach.

- Detect the available number of CPUs on the local machine.

Is the following command general?

```
mpiexec -n *
```

Thanks of any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can search for "Microsoft MPI" or "MPICH2" in the path string, but that's certainly not a general approach.

There is no general approach on Windows (as opposed on Linux and MacOS). Programs can be installed everywhere though they are generally in:

- `C:\Program Files`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)`
- `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\...`

An alternative solution is to **search for a MPI program in the `PATH`**. This solution require to modify the `PATH` in the system properties. There are Linux related tools to search programs in it like `locate`. Such tools can be executed from Windows using a Linux-friendly console (eg. Git-Bash, Cmder, etc.). Batch shell script are very limited and clearly not user-friendly. Powershell may have some similar feature (though it requires a Powershell console).

This is a mess since tools like CMake (which barely supports MPI) spend a lot of effort and runtime to search for many frequent locations so to search libraries with no guarantee.

---

> Detect the available number of CPUs on the local machine.

In Powershell, you can use the following code:

```
$processor = Get-ComputerInfo -Property CsProcessors
$CPU_COUNT = $processor.CsProcessors.NumberOfCores
```

assuming you want to extract the number of core, or otherwise:

```
$processor = Get-ComputerInfo -Property CsProcessors
$CPU_COUNT = $processor.CsProcessors.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

assuming you want to extract the number of logical cores (ie. hyper-threads).

Whether you should use one or the other is dependent of your target application and the target machine. I advise to use the number of core.

An alternative solution is to use the **`hw-loc`** tool also available on Linux and portable on many platforms. It is also a great tool to understand, profile and control the platform configuration (especially on NUMA systems).

---

Note that using MPI on Windows is very uncommon these days. A lot of high-performance tools/libraries supports mainly Linux (and not Windows) since 100% of the top 500 supercomputers (meant to run MPI programs) operate on Linux.

Comment: Thank you, so yeah some trial and error on the path cannot be avoided.